# Prove that these two connected Petersen subgraphs are Hamiltonian (or not).

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I'm currently revisiting some graph theory and have ran into the following graph.

I am to prove if it is Hamiltonian or not.

To my knowledge there is no definite or "good" theorems to determine if a graph is Hamiltonian (or not, i.e. Ore's, Dirac's) nor do we have any time/space efficient algorithms for checking larger graphs.

I have checked algorithmically that this connected graph of two Petersen subgraphs is not Hamiltonian though I don't know how to prove it mathematically.

Can anyone suggest a good angle of approach or a possible solution to mathematically proving that the graph below is not Hamiltonian?

Is it plausible to prove that it is non-Hamiltonian by the fact Petersen graphs are not Hamiltonian?

[image: Graph in Question]

Comment: To answer your last question: Yes. If you had a Hamiltonian cycle in your graph, then you could obviously get a Hamiltonian cycle in the Petersen graph. Let's say you start on the left side and follow your alleged Hamilton cycle in the big graph. When you hit the point where you were going to go due East, instead go due North or South along the edge of your original Petersen graph, and then proceed as if you were coming from the East on your big cycle.

Comment: Are you suggesting to consider the graph as two Petersen components and to then prove by contradiction on the fact Petersen graphs are not Hamiltonian?